# How to clear the result of a command?

Tags: git, bash, shell, awk

So, imagine that the result of this cmd: `git l | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}’` is this hash `709bc16`

When  I run this cmd:

`git show --pretty="format:" --name-only $(git l | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}’)`

I get this error

`fatal: ambiguous argument '709bc16': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>…]’`

When I try directly `git show --pretty="format:" 709bc16`

then cmd is executed successfully.

I don't know even what to ask. I believe is something about the format of the result of this cmd: `$(git l | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}’)`

Comment: What is `git l`? `git log`?

Comment: What is `git l` aliased to? It looks like the output contains an invisible character, possibly a carriage return? What is the output of `git l | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' | hexdump -C`?

Comment: @chepner that's right.. here's how it shows: `[33m709bc16[32m`.

Comment: You're getting the ANSI escape characters that `git` uses to colorize the output; the best solution would be to modify `git l` (or create a new alias) to output uncolorizeed text.

Comment: Unless you specify what `git l` is defined, your question will be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the diagnosis in the comments of extra invisible characters surrounding your revision shortname, your `git l` command is probably an alias of a "porcelain" (UI) git command, not a "plumbing" (shell script) command.

Porcelain commands are more user-friendly on the command line, often using color, indentation, and ASCII art to display your repository. However, the exact output isn't specified, and is subject to change and evolution across versions. Plumbing commands are low-level commands with exactly-specified plaintext outputs designed specifically for cases like shell scripting.

You may want to scan the [git man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) for relevant plumbing commands like [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).